# HTML5 audio/video doesn't work using fancybox overlay on iOS

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When I embed an HTML5 audio/video tag into the fancybox overlay, the audio/video player doesn't display using any iOS device (iPhone/iPad).  When calling open_audio_overlay() you can use this MP3 http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3.  I am using version 2 of fancybox (the latest code).  I have provided the following code that I am using:

CSS:

```
div.overlay .fancybox-skin
{
    background: #1f1f1f;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
}

div.overlay-content
{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

div#audio-overlay
{
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="audio-overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content">
        <div id="audio-title" style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"></div>
            <audio id="audio-player" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function open_audio_overlay(url, title)
{
    $('#audio-player').attr('type', 'audio/mp3');
    $('#audio-player').attr('src', url);

    $('#audio-title').html(title);

    $.fancybox.open($('#audio-overlay'),
    {
        wrapCSS: 'overlay',
        openEffect: 'none',
            helpers:
            {
                overlay:
                {
                    opacity: 0.50,
                    closeClick: false,
                    css:
                    {
                        cursor: 'auto'
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced problems with "controls" and "autoplay" attributes added to html5 video elements when viewed in Safari Mobile on the iPad. I believe my problems stemmed from the removal of "controls" and/or setting controls to not be displayed but I would attempt adjusting these first and see if you can get a change from there.

Comment: Removing those attributes didn't make a difference.  I had previously done this.  I believe this is a fancybox issue because if I use the audio/video element outside of fancybox, my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, turns out I am using an old version of fancybox (even though the file version states 2.0.6 at the top in the comment).  I downloaded the latest and it now works.